# How to solve this problem of access to Mailtrap via Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, verify

I'm trying to do a mail check with Laravel 5.8, and I use Mailtrap, but every time I have an access error to the Mailtrap account I don't know why? And I don't know what the best way to do this is.

I tried `php artisan cache:clear, clear:config, dump-autoload, config:cache`, etc. I changed the security of my account to allow application access.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525 
MAIL_USERNAME=sanogosanata15@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=assetou5jtm
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**Error**

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
>   "sanogosanata15@gmail.com" using three possible authenticators.
>   Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response ▶
>       ". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code
>   250 but got an empty response.

Comment: You configured gmail credentials. You need to use mailtrap credentials. In addition, you should probably remove your gmail credentials.

Comment: I used my gmail information to create my mailtrap account

Comment: the problem is solved I confused the information I provided with what I was assigned, thank you.but now I don't receive the confirmation message that I send from my application

Comment: You might need to white list email addresses with the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your mailtrap credential is wrong, you may need to signup mailtrap and use the username ang password provided.

[image]

Comment: I used the username provided but it's return the same error

Comment: the problem is solved I confused the information I provided with what I was assigned, thank you.but now I don't receive the confirmation message that I send from my application

Comment: @Inconito1018 Check your spam folder.